# Best practice to render Laravel site in other language

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, localization, google-translate

## Description

I have a Laravel site is in English. I want to make it compatible with Dutch also.

---

I start my homepage small, it only contain 3 sentences.

```
<h1 class="heading">My business WiFi</h1>
<p>Management via this page both your <a>private WiFi</a> as your <a>guest wifi</a>.</p>
<p>Or follow the use of your WiFi via our <a>statistics</a>.</p>
```

which will render this

```
My business WiFi
Management via this page both your private WiFi as your guest wifi.
Or follow the use of your WiFi via our statistics.
```

---

## Attempt

I've installed this [Laravel package](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization) and did all the installation steps from that repo.

My routes, service provider, alias, middleware, resources/lang/ , and the laravellocalization.php are all in to place.

---

**routes.php**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(), 'middleware' => [ 'localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect','localize'] ], function(){

    Route::get('/homepage', 'homepageController@index');

});
```

---

**update providers array**

```
Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\LaravelLocalizationServiceProvider::class
```

**update alias**

```
'LaravelLocalization'   => Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Facades\LaravelLocalization::class
```

---

**update $routeMiddleware**

```
'localize' => \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LaravelLocalizationRoutes::class,
'localizationRedirect' => \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LaravelLocalizationRedirectFilter::class,
'localeSessionRedirect' => \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LocaleSessionRedirect::class
```

---

**/config/laravellocalization.php**

```
<?php

return [

    'supportedLocales' => [
        'en'          => ['name' => 'English','script' => 'Latn', 'native' => 'English'],
        'nl'          => ['name' => 'Dutch','script' => 'Latn', 'native' => 'Nederlands'],
    ],

    'useAcceptLanguageHeader' => true,
    'hideDefaultLocaleInURL' => false,
];
```

---

**Result**

When I visit

```
http://site/nl/homepage
```

OR

```
http://site/en/homepage
http://site/homepage
```

I saw my site load as it should in English, which is good.

It return `404` when I visit some other site that not declared.

**China**

`Ex. http://site/zh/homepage`

Which is good because it works as intended.

---

But my main goal is I want see my site in Dutch when I land on

http://site/nl/homepage

I should see this 3 sentences below in **Dutch**

```
My business WiFi
Management via this page both your private WiFi as your guest wifi.
Or follow the use of your WiFi via our statistics.
```

---

## Questions

Is this something that I need to declare `/resources/lang/nl/texts.php`?

Or is this something that can be achievable via library / plug-in / framework?

Comment: Have you translated strings you are trying to see in Dutch? I feel you are expecting these strings to be autotranslated somehow :)

Comment: I am trying to look for a library that will help me do that. Do you one and would like to recommend ?

Comment: Should I start create a file in `/resources/lang/nl/` and create an array of translating stings there ? If I do that, how do display those strings instead of english.

Comment: I think there are some, which provide translation service from Google or Bing, but are you really want your site to be autotranslatable? If you really do, there are plenty of JavaScript-based plugins which can acveive just that without any Laravel help.

Comment: Just a min, I will create an Answer

Comment: The first step would be that `autotranslation` would be the way to go. 
I never done this before, if the `autotranslation` is good enough, then I will be okay with it.
But it has to be review by native dutch speaker.

Then, my next step is to allow modification ability - just in case the translation is a bit off or way off like create a array of strings in `/resources/lang/nl/`.

Comment: I will modify my answer to reflect that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create appropriate files and fill them with translated string (or arrays). If any of the translated string is not found, Laravel will fallback to `config('fallback_locale')`.

With

```
// resources/lang/nl/texts.php
<?php return [
   'heading' => 'Mijn zakelijke WiFi',
   'line1' => 'Beheer via deze pagina zowel uw <a>private WiFi</a> als uw <a>gast wifi</a>.',
   'line2' => 'Of volg het gebruik van uw WiFi via onze <a>statistieken</a>.'
];
```

and

```
// resources/lang/en/texts.php
<?php return [
   'heading' => 'My business WiFi',
   'line1' => 'Management via this page both your <a>private WiFi</a> as your <a>guest wifi</a>.',
   'line2' => 'Or follow the use of your WiFi via our <a>statistics</a>.'
];
```

you will be able to retrieve these strings (prepending filename) anywhere by translate functions like `trans('texts.heading')`, `trans_choice('texts.heading', $count)` or special Blade directive `@lang('texts.heading')`

Your view could look like this:

```
<h1 class="heading">@lang('texts.heading')</h1>
<p>{!! trans('texts.line1') !!}</p>
<p>{!! trans('texts.line2') !!}</p>
```

Since there is HTML markup in your translated strings, you will have to unescape them by using `{!! ... !!}`.

In order to ease the pain of translation, there is [Laravel Translation Manager](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-translation-manager), great plugin by Barry vd. Heuvel. You can let your users modify these strings and catch untranslated string automatically.

In general, I will not recommend autotranslation services if you require quality translation. If you don't, just consider javascript library for that.

Comment: So what will my view look like ?? as of now, this what I have `<h1 class="heading">My business WiFi</h1>
<p>Management via this page both your <a>private WiFi</a> as your <a>guest wifi</a>.</p>
<p>Or follow the use of your WiFi via our <a>statistics</a>.</p>
 `